# ASP.NET Send Email

Tags: asp.net, email

I am trying to send a email when user clicks submit in a contact us page but for some reason its not working, what am I doing wrong? (PS email & password was omited from this code snippet but included in actual solution.

Thanks

Code in web.config:

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="order@test.com">
    <network host="smtp.gmail.com"
             userName="" //my email
             password="" //password deleted for privacy reasons
             defaultCredentials="false"
             port="456"
             enableSsl="true" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

code in asp.net contact form:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("test@gmail.com"));
        mail.Subject = "Test";
        mail.Body = "Message was sent from" + txtName.text + txtComment.text;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.SendAsync(mail, null);
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by not working ??

Comment: Change `SendAsync()` to `Send()` and look at the exception.

Comment: page seemed to be loading for quite a while but the email is never received.

Also I tried setting Async="true" still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gmails uses port `465`, not `456` for SSL SMTP. From [here](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287&rd=1):

> Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server - requires TLS1 or SSL:  smtp.gmail.com
>
> Use Authentication: Yes
>
> Port for TLS/STARTTLS: 587
>
> Port for SSL: 465

Comment: Did you catch an exception as Slaks suggested? Also, do you own `test@gmail.com` or have you changed that for this post? (because that's where your mail is being sent)

Comment: test@gmail.com is changed to email and yes but no exception was thrown

Comment: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: Check your firewall isn't blocking the port.

Comment: Turned off firewall- still same prob

Comment: Not sure what it could be. Assuming you're correctly replacing `order@test.com` with the correct Gmail address (`test.com` domain is wrong since you want to access Gmail's SMTP), and your web.config file is being correctly loaded, it seems like the error is somewhere else (other code/environment issues).

Answer (score 1):

The "other" possible reason:

- Does your code "work" when developing locally, but stops working when you "publish"/ftp/copy, etc. your files to your web host?
- **If** `Yes`: check your host's `trust` settings for ASP.Net. If it's `medium trust` (which is likely in shared hosting), then note that you **cannot use any port *other* than port 25** for SMTP in **medium trust**.

It works locally (dev) because in local dev/VS environment, ASP.Net runs in `full trust`.

REF (MSDN Blogs): [SMTP Problems when ASP.Net is not running in full-trust](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alvar/archive/2010/02/08/smtp-problems-when-asp-net-is-not-running-in-full-trust.aspx)

Comment: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: @rikket didn't say you should use port 25 - Google Mail doesn't work on port 25. I'm saying that *if* (and only if) `medium trust` is set, you *cannot* use any other port than port 25 (and therefore will not work with Google Mail).