# Sending Email In C# MVC..On Local host..not working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, smtp, sendmail, smtpclient, system.net.mail

Im trying to send out a basic email, using C# mvc...for some reason it wont work.. i    tried many different solutions, but keep getting same error in browser that says" operation has timed out"..which i think is a connection problem. Error starts at" client.Send(mail); im doing this on my local machine.I tried using port 587,465,995,25, but no luck. I dont get any errors, in the compiler in Visual Studio, when i build it. I just get the error, in the web browser, on line" client.Send(mail);"

Controller:

```
  public void SendEmail(History hi)
  {
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();   //server type
    client.Port = 587;                      
    client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";         //google
    client.EnableSsl = true;                //SSl set to true
    client.Timeout = 10000;
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("papasmurf985@gmail.com", "******"); 

    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("papasmurf985@gmail.com", "papasmurf985@gmail.com", "Test Score", "Your score is" + hi.score);
    mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;

    client.Send(mail);                      
  }
```

web.config:

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
      <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" />
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

I also tried this in web.config:

```
<system.net>
   <mailSettings>
     <smtp from="no-reply@no-reply.com">
       <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" enableSsl="true"
                userName="papasmurf985@gmail.com" password="PASSWORD" />
     </smtp>
   </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14025272/1352471

Comment: I hope that's not your real gmail password

Comment: what's the exception?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following pls

```
public void SendMessage(string toAddress, string subjectText, string bodyText)
{
    //create a object to hold the message
    MailMessage newMessage = new MailMessage();

    //Create addresses
    MailAddress senderAddress = new MailAddress(your_gmail_address);
    MailAddress recipentAddress = new MailAddress(toAddress);

    //Now create the full message
    newMessage.To.Add(recipentAddress);
    newMessage.From = senderAddress;
    newMessage.Subject = subjectText;
    newMessage.Body = bodyText;

    //Create the SMTP Client object, which do the actual sending
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(your_gmail_server_address, your_gmail_port)
    {
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(your_gmail_address, your_password),
        EnableSsl = true
    };


    //now send the message
    client.Send(newMessage);
}
```

This code is working for me

Comment: Thanks All I just got it...the orginal code works..just i had to try it from a different location.The connection i was on had blocked Ports..

Answer (score 0):

I would first make sure that your ISP doesn't block external SMTP servers